# LuaTeX: \fontfeature{Fractions=On} turns first digits into superscripts

Tags: luatex, fractions

With `LuaTeX`, all of a sudden the first digits of any numbers outside `$math$` (and `siunitx`'s `\num`) are turned into superscripts if I set `\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Fractions=On}` -- independent of the fonts I use. In each case only the last digit of a number is in normal font, the first digits are superscript.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Fractions=On} % <-- that's it
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
% \setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\begin{document}
blabla 6176 787347 125\footnote{bla 123} \num{10} \num{19827}

$1234 + 567 = 8910$

\medskip
\textsf{blabla 6176 787347 125\footnote{bla 123} \num{10} \num{19827}}

$\mathsf{1234 + 567 = 8910}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: As far as I can see `LuaTeX` created something in the first run because `luaotfload` has been changed.

Comment: I get same here, I pinged the luaotfload maintainers in this site's chat,.

Comment: it also happens for `xelatex`

Comment: it doesn't happen in texlive 2017 but it seems to be due to a font update rather than luatex or luaotfload.

Comment: It seems to be a font problem. I get it like Herbert with xelatex too (and also when fontspec is not used). But the older lualatex fontloader seems to have "hidden" the font bug.

Comment: "It seems to be a font problem." Sure? With Linux Libertine O it's the same as with Libertinus Serif.

Comment: then probably libertinus is faulty too. ;-) I have no idea how the frac property should work, but if xelatex fails on it (which uses harfbuzz) then there is a high probability that the font hasn't implemented it correctly. But I asked on the context lists. Perhaps the luatex fontloader can work around the problem.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenType fractions feature should not be enabled globally, and should instead be enabled selectively for parts of text containing fractions (some fonts try to make it work globally, but it is often buggy since this kind of behavior is hard to achieve with OpenType features):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\begin{document}
blabla 6176 787347 125\footnote{bla 123} 10 19827
{\addfontfeatures{Fractions=On} 1234/1234}

$1234 + 567 = 8910$

\medskip
\textsf{blabla 6176 787347 125\footnote{bla 123} 10 19827
{\addfontfeatures{Fractions=On} 1234/1234}}

$\mathsf{1234 + 567 = 8910}$
\end{document}
```

With XeTeX this gives:
[image: XeTeX output]

As a bonus, with XeTeX<sup>1</sup> if you use fraction slash (U+2044) the fraction (or numerator and denominator) feature will be activated automatically for the sequence of numbers around it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\begin{document}
blabla 6176 787347 125\footnote{bla 123} 10 19827 1234⁄1234

$1234 + 567 = 8910$

\medskip
\textsf{blabla 6176 787347 125\footnote{bla 123} 10 19827 1234⁄1234}

$\mathsf{1234 + 567 = 8910}$
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> That is actually a HarfBuzz feature, following Unicode recommendation, so it works anywhere HarfBuzz is used, e.g. In Firefox and Google Chrome.